# Debugging R script called from Python

Tags: linux, python-2.7, debugging, remote-debugging, rscript

I have a python 2.7 script that calls R script like this:
`subprocess.Popen("Rscript myscript.R", shell=True).wait()` 
The code runs on Linux.  Not being very famiiar with R nor Linux, what is the best way for me to debug this code either on Linux, or remotely from Windows, or even locally on Windows?  Thanks.